# Official Facebook examples crashes (GraphApiSample)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I started to work with **facebook-android-sdk-3.5.2.**

The SDK project also contains varius sample examples for using the api like:

- HelloFacebookSample: A simple activity you can log in and do stuff, it works great.

Next thing i wanted to try the next example called:

- GraphApiSample, which **i had problem with.**

After i launch this app, i got this error: (Logcat):

```
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.facebook.samples.graphapi/com.facebook.samples.graphapi.GraphApiSampleActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both context and applicationId must be non-null
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2649)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both context and applicationId must be non-null
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(AppEventsLogger.java:308)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(AppEventsLogger.java:292)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at com.facebook.samples.graphapi.GraphApiSampleActivity.onResume(GraphApiSampleActivity.java:76)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5121)
11-11 15:22:40.008: E/AndroidRuntime(14048):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
```

Well i see:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both context and applicationId must be non-null**

Okay, but i did not changed a thing in the code. **It should be work, right?**

I tried to:

- Delete project, and import
- Delete project, and add a new android project from existing code
- Clean my project
- Delete facebook sdk library dependency and reimport, then clean again.

Same result after all of these.

Please if somebody is familiar with this prob. help me.

**E D I T:**

For some reason, this official facebook sample does not contains appId.
Thanks for the suggest!

Comment: try to set the app_id in the strings.xml or add it

Comment: Add it as an answer and i will accept, thank you.

Comment: The current GraphApiSampleActivity has APP_ID defined in the class already.  I used version 3.6.0 of the SDK.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to set the `app_id` in the `strings.xml` or add it. It is also mentioned in the getting started tutorial here: [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

An additional step:
Create a meta-data with the name `com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId` and the value `@string/app_id` in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have (or want) the facebook app id stored in your strings.xml (e.g., maybe you receive the facebook app id dynamically over the internet), then you can call this method instead to activate...
`AppEventsLogger.activateApp(Context context, String facebookAppId)`

You should call this in the `onResume()` method of your activities:

`@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(...);
}`

Comment: Where is the best place to call the method?

Comment: You should add it in the `onResume()` method of your activity. I've updated my answer with a code snippet.

Comment: I have an applicationID and I followed the steps (put it in strings.xml and in manifest.xml) but still got the error. Any idea why? In the meantime, your suggestion allowed me to continue developing my app (gave you +1)

Comment: Hiya Zvi, Not sure, really. You'd be best off posting a new question with your appropriate code and stack trace. :-)